# ASP.NET MVC 5 Authorization Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on a project and need to add authorization to several functions. Currently, the setup is very simple. All I want to do is sign in and be authorized. However, the sign in function succeeds while **User.Identity.IsAuthenticated** remains set to **false**, resulting in no access to anything labelled [Authorize].

How should I go about fixing this? Should I check for entries in **DBO.AspNetUserLogins** to see if the login was logged?

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel details, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        AppUser user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(details.Email);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, details.Password, false, false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                   //Just curious if this is true.
                }
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(LoginViewModel.Email), " Invalid user or password");
    }

    return View(details);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the order of the app.UserAuthentication() and App.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute() in Startup.cs matters. When I put the UseAuthentication before the route stuff, it suddenly worked. Kind of makes sense that it is needed during routing.